# $\|P(A)^* P(A)\| = \|(\overline{P}P)(A)\|$ where $A$ is a bounded self adjoint operator and $P$ is a polynomial in $A$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I am following the proof of a lemma in Reed & Simon that states:

> Let $A$ be a bounded self adjoint operator. Then $$\|P(A)\| = \sup_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} |P(\lambda)|.$$

In their proof the give the following equality

$$\|P(A)\|^2 = \|P(A)^*P(A)\| = \|(\overline{P}P)(A)\|.$$

How did they obtain the equality $\|P(A)^* P(A)\| = \|(\overline{P}P)(A)\|$? Where does this come from?

Moreover, how does $A$ being self-adjoint imply $P(A)$ is self adjoint?

Comment: $(\sum a_kA^{k})^{*}=\sum \overline {a_k} A^{k}$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you. Sorry for the simple question, but where does this follow from?

Comment: $A$ being self-adjoint does not generally imply that $P(A)$ is self-adjoint for every polynomial $P$.  Related things are true, however, for example, that the operator $P(A)^* P(A)$ is self-adjoint for every polynomial $P$ and every operator $A$ (i.e., whether or not $A$ is self-adjoint), or that $P(A)^* P(A)$ is a polynomial in $A$ (namely $(\overline{P} P)(A)$) whenever $A$ is self-adjoint (where in general it is only a polynomial in both $A$ and $A^*$). Without more context it is not clear what Reed and Simon might be using, but it may be some combination of those facts.

Comment: @leslietownes Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed element of an algebra $A$, the map $P \mapsto P(A)$ is a morphism of algebras, which means that for all $P,Q$, $(P+Q)(A) = P(A) + Q(A)$ and $(PQ)(A) = P(A)Q(A)$. Moreover, we have that $P(A)^* = \overline{P}(A^*)$.

The proof of these facts is straightforward (using the coefficients of the polynomials) and can be found in any book on linear algebra.

From the above,

- assuming $A$ is self-adjoint, $P(A)^*P(A) = \overline{P}(A^*)P(A) = \overline{P}(A)P(A) = (\overline{P}P)(A)$;
- if $P$ is a real-valued polynomial, if $A = A^*$, then $P(A) ^* = \overline{P}(A^*) = P(A)$, so $P(A)$ is also self-adjoint.

Comment: The formula $\|P(A)\|=\max_{z\in\sigma(A)}|P(z)|$ holds for any normal operator $A$,. The proof is  based on elementary analysis of the spectra.

Answer (score 2):

For every bounded operator $B:X\to X,$ where $X$ is a Banach space, and every polynomial $P(z)$ there holds $$\sigma(P(B))=P(\sigma (B))\quad (1)$$ If $B$ is a normal bounded operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ we have $$\|B\|=\max_{\lambda\in \sigma(B)}|\lambda|\quad(2)$$
Let $A\in B(\mathcal{H})$ be a normal operator. Then for any polynomial $P(z)$ the operator $P(A)$ is normal. Hence applying $(2)$ and $(1)$ gives
$$\|P(A)\|=\max_{\mu\in\sigma(P(A))}|\mu|=\max_{\lambda\in\sigma(A)}|P(\lambda)|$$

Comment: +A reference that $(1)$ holds in any unital Banach Algebra can be found [here](http://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~richard/teaching/s2014/Course_Wilde.pdf) Proposition 1.14.  In fact, in a non-unital Banach Algebra this holds for polynomials with no constant coefficient and the spectra computed after adjoining a unit.

Comment: @JohnDoe The proof for unital Banach algebras is identical as for operators. It is  based on the fundamental theorem of algebra and simple algebraic manipulations. It can be further extended to functions holomorphic in an open neighborhood of the spectrum of an element of a Banach algebra.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.